# Converting a string into Linq lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, lucene, ravendb

We are using `RavenDB` in our project and we have a search panel that let users search documents using different criteria. Take a building age for example.These input data are sent from out web client in query string and I have to translate them to Lucene syntax in order to get the result from `RavenDB` but I am thinking that it would be easier for me to rely on Raven Linq Provider to do this job for me then instead of having :

```
Age_Range : [Ix5 TO NULL]
```

I can have :

```
b=>b.Age>=5
```

Then all I have to do is to convert this string into a lambda expression.

What I am doing right now is to compile a code like this :

```
public class BuildingQueryBuilderXYZ:IQueryBuilder<Building>
{
     public IRavenQueryable<Building> BuildQuery(IDocumentSession session)
     {
           return session.Query<Building>().Where(b=>b.Age>=5);  
     }
}
```

And it is working but I have to compile an assembly for each request which is not an efficient way of searching the database.

If I could find a way to convert this string `b=>b.Age>=5` into a lambda expression I think my problem would be solved :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I found [Dynamic Linq Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Library/) that somehow does what I'd like to do but it has its own syntax (not the same as linq). Here's an example :

```
var query = session.Query<Person>().Where("Age <= 11 And Age >= 5");
```

and it is working :)

**UPDATE** : if I wanted to write the same in Lucene syntax it would be : `Age_Range : [Ix5 TO Ix11]` . And `I` means integer here which means that I have to know the type in order to generate a correct query but in the first version all I care is that `Age` is a number and I leave it to `RavenDB Linq Provider` to do the magic for me :)